# 'T' is not identical to 'Int'

Tags: swift, dictionary, type-conversion

I'm trying some sample code in Swift and combined two principles: Array.map and Extension. Unfortunately, I get the error code "'T' is not identical to 'Int'" (line 3). So my question should probably be: how can I transform a T array into a Int array?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Cheers.

```
extension Array {    
    func translateToDigitalNames()-> [String] {
        var numbers : [Int] = self

        let digitNames =
            [0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two",   3: "Three", 4: "Four",
            5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"]

        var strings = numbers.map {
            (var number) -> String in
            var output = ""
            while number > 0 {
                output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
                number /= 10
            }
            return output
        }
        return strings
    }
}

let x = [26, 158, 610]
x.translateToDigitalNames()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the problem into 3 distinct subproblems.

The first is translating an integer into a string representation, implemented as a static method:

```
private static func translateToDigitalName(var number: Int) -> String {
    var output = ""

    while number > 0 {
        output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
        number /= 10
    }

    return output
}
```

The reasons for making it a separate function are: separation of concerns, reusability, readability.

Next, we can implement a static method that, given an array of integers, returns an array of their respective string representations:

```
private static func translateToDigitalNames(numbers: [Int])-> [String] {
    return numbers.map { self.translateToDigitalName($0) }
}
```

Last, the actual array extension. The approach I'm using is to filter the array by excluding elements not castable to Int:

```
func translateToDigitalNames()-> [String] {
    let numbers: [Int] = self.filter { $0 is Int }.map { $0 as Int }
    return Array.translateToDigitalNames(numbers)
}
```

If you want the translation to fail if at least one array element is not an Int, just add an explicit check and return nil in that case:

```
func translateToDigitalNames()-> [String]? {
    let numbers: [Int] = self.filter { $0 is Int }.map { $0 as Int }

    if numbers.count != self.count {
        return nil
    }

    return Array.translateToDigitalNames(numbers)
}
```

Note that the return type is now an optional.

Last thing, rather than creating the `digitNames` array at every function invocation, I've moved it as a private global and immutable variable

The full code is available on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jeden/e51ca85320638927cd87)

Side note: the `translateToDigitalNames` and `translateToDigitalName` can be moved outside of the array extension, as global and public functions - and that's actually what I'd recommend in case you need to reuse them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `numbers` array with a map function as well, like:

```
var numbers = map { $0 as Int }
```

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure how this works, but it does. But why use a map function twice now? I am bit confused...

Comment: @etri With this, you actually go through each element of self, and cast it to an int, basically, what you wanted in orded to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to write such kind of extension since it applies only to `[Int]` arrays. What should happen if you would do

```
["some", "strings"].translateToDigitalNames()
```

Instead use a function like this:

```
func translateToDigitalNames(numbers:[Int])-> [String] {

  let digitNames =
  [0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two",   3: "Three", 4: "Four",
    5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"]
  var strings = numbers.map {
    (var number) -> String in
    var output = ""
    while number > 0 {
      output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
      number /= 10
    }
    return output
  }
  return strings
}

let x = [26, 158, 610]
translateToDigitalNames(x)
```

So the compiler ensures you always supply a `[Int]`

Comment: You're right about the extension not being a good idea. It was however an exercise for me to get experience with extensions and using 'self' as a variable. But thanks anyway for your clear reply!